# cte recursive part only returns one row

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

If I don't have a join in the recursive part of my CTE, I only get one row per recursion, why is that?

Code tested on SQL Server 2016 and Azure SQL database:

```
DECLARE @Number TABLE (Number INT);

INSERT INTO @Number (Number)
VALUES (1), (2);

;WITH _cte AS 
(
     SELECT Number
     FROM @Number
     UNION ALL
     SELECT _cte.Number
     FROM _cte
)
SELECT *
FROM _cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2); -- just call recursive part twice to see the issue
```

In the result I get number `2` in each recursion/depth.

I would expect the current rows to be repeated in each recursion, hence an exponential increase in the number of rows

Expected output

```
Number
--------------------    
1   -- from anchor
2   
1   -- first recursion
2   
1   -- second recursion
2   
1   
2
```

Actual output:

```
Number
--------------------    
1   -- from anchor
2   
2   -- first recursion  
2   -- second recursion
```

Comment: That code, as written, would throw an error.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2007/10/25/recursive-ctes/

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith - that link confirmed what I suspected with my answer.  The order of the results as I was trying different queries looked like a stack with results pushed in order and the last item on the stack popped for recursion and the post you linked confirmed that SQL Server really does work that way internally.

Answer (score 2):

From some testing, it appears that SQL recursion occurs depth first beginning with the last row returned from the initial query.  As soon as it has reached `MAXRECURSION`, the query terminates with an error (e.g. `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 2 has been exhausted before statement completion.`) and returns whatever results it reached before the error.  You can verify this by inserting 2,1 instead of 1,2 in your insert statement, or by inserting 1,2,3 into your `@Number` table.  If you insert 1,2,3 into `@Number`, your results returned would be

```
1  -- From anchor
2  -- From anchor
3  -- From anchor
3  -- 1st recursion from last row of anchor query
3  -- Recursion from the row from the line above this (2nd recursion)
-- Query terminates after MAXRECURSION reached on an item and does not attempt recursion on 1 or 2
```

Typically, when using recursion, you join the CTE to itself or some other table with some criteria in the where statement or the on criteria in the join that would limit the recursion based on the available data (not just repeated recursion through the same elements).  For example (using the same `@Number` table from your question):

```
DECLARE @Number TABLE (Number INT);

INSERT @Number
(
    Number
)
VALUES (1),
(2);
WITH _cte2
AS
    (SELECT 
        Number
        ,0 as 'RecursionCount'
    FROM
        @Number

    UNION ALL
        SELECT
        Number
        ,RecursionCount + 1
    FROM
        _cte2
    WHERE
        RecursionCount <= 1
    )
SELECT * FROM _cte2 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2);
```

In the above example, the query will limit its own recursion in the where statement and never reach MAXRECURSION, so the query will be able to finish.  You'll also note that the order of results returned confirms my suspicion that recursion is depth first beginning with the last item:

```
Number  RecursionCount
1       0
2       0
2       1
2       2
1       1
1       2
```

Comment: Hat's off to you Shawn.  You put the explanation to the ordering oddity I found.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit to this:

```
with 

    _cte as (

        SELECT num, 0 iteration
        FROM @Number

        UNION ALL
        SELECT num, iteration + 1
        FROM _cte
        where iteration <= 3 -- comment this line out and compare

    )

    SELECT *
    FROM _cte
    --OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2); -- comment this line out and compare as well
```

I then compared the results with that when commenting out the 'where iteration <= 3'.  It took me awhile to realize, but the ordering of the results were not what I expected.

[image]

I think that when the error for max loops hits, or when you put in the option to cut off the max recursion, it is somehow cutting off the latter results that you would find in rows 7-10.